# Users are not scrolling below full page image, but clicking on nav links

Tags: menu, homepage, page-layout

I have a typical page layout with a header across the top of the pages containing a logo on the left and nav on the right.

The homepage starts with some intro text (which takes up most, but not all of the page "above the fold") and moves down to an important list of case studies.

The problem I have is that generally users are clicking on the nav links, missing the important links to the case studies. It appears that users are far more willing to click on something (the nav links) than scroll down.

How do I reverse this?

I could make it harder to click on the nav links by "hiding" the links behind a hamburger icon (two clicks) but this doesn't seem good usability.

I can't really move the case study links up because the heading and intro text take up the space at the top of the homepage.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: How do you know this is a problem? The point of navigation is to allow people to get to the part of the site they want. maybe these users don't want case studies? If you don't want people to navigate off the homepage then don't provide them navigation. But I assume the site has other features other than case studies that you want people to find.

Comment: There are two types of pages. Case studies and 'info' pages (about, services, contact etc). I would like users to look at a case study or two, before visiting the drier more functional 'info' pages. But on the homepage users are clicking on the nav links (to the 'info' pages), rather than the case studies.

Comment: As I want to 'direct' users towards the case study list / links, then perhaps I have to make it 'harder' to visit the info pages, by hiding the links behind a hamburger icon which would require two clicks.

Comment: @Markeee My guess is that users are not clicking because: they don't realise (nor bother to investigate) they have a second option, what they see is interesting enough for them to proceed. So either hide them the conflicting elements or bring to front the ones you want them to focus. Or both options.

Answer (score 1):

You have to sacrifice some elements to bring others to the front.

Some suggestions that might help:

- **Hide the intro text for small screens**, below the case studies or behind an expandable panel.
- Hide the navigation links as you suggest.
- Double the elements you want to give importance to. This would depend on the page layout but maybe including Case1 Case2 as links in the navigation could help.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. I'm moving towards "hiding" the nav links behind a hamburger font.